# The 'return' function

Tags: python, measurement

I am trying to make a measurement machine with python, but when I enter the measurements it just goes on with the code, I want it to stop processing once I get a result, here is the code I have done so far:

I need it to stop after "`print math.sqrt(int(h1)**2 + int(h2)**2)`"

```
need = raw_input("What do you need to Use?")

if need == "pythagoras" or "Pythagoras":
    pythagoras = raw_input("What side do you Need?")

if pythagoras == "hypotenuse" or "Hypotenuse":
    h1 = int(raw_input("Known Side 1"))
    h2 = int(raw_input("Known Side 2"))

import math
print math.sqrt(int(h1)**2 + int(h2)**2)
```

Comment: What do you mean "it just goes on with the code"?

Comment: If there's no code after that `print`, the script will stop automatically. And secondly `return` works only inside a function.

Comment: sorry, i have more of the code, but this is all i need to display because it is all the same, anyway, it just goes on to the next question, but i want it to stop after this code

Comment: Pretty sure you've got a logic error in your if statements. Should be `if need in ('xxx','yyy')`. The `or` bit will make it always truthy, no? Furthermore, you might as well 'lower' the input and compare it that way rather than trying variants of the same word.

Comment: I think you need to show more of your code.

Comment: I think you need to read some Python tutorials. Your `if` statements are not going to work in the way you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling [`sys.exit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit) will immediately terminate the execution of the program, like `return` does for functions:

```
import sys

...
print math.sqrt(int(h1)**2 + int(h2)**2)
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Don't forget to `import sys`. If you don't want to import, use `raise SystemExit, 0` (It's the same).

Comment: its not working, will it be because im using python 2.7.2?

Comment: @RossGibson You likely forgot to `import sys` at the beginning of the program. `sys.exit()` works in Python 2.7.x.

Comment: I would suggest putting your script inside a function and using return, and calling that function when your script starts. It's just cleaner than having a bunch of random sys.exit() everywhere.

Comment: sorry, im new to python, how would i go about doing that Thomas?

Comment: @RossGibson It's as simple as moving all your stuff into a function, and then calling that function at the lowest indentation level (which is what will be executed when you import the module). Remember to add a single sys.exit() after that function call if you want to achieve the same effect.

Comment: but how do i move my stuff into a function?

Comment: @RossGibson Oh, ok. Here: http://pastebin.com/YZxYbY0n. Though you will learn about functions soon probably, then.

Comment: thanks again Thomas, you've saved my script

Answer (score 0):

̶N̶o̶t̶ ̶n̶e̶e̶d̶ ̶i̶m̶p̶o̶r̶t̶ ̶s̶y̶s̶,̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶e̶x̶i̶t̶(̶)̶ ̶c̶a̶n̶ ̶e̶x̶i̶t̶.̶

It's more clean if pass 0 argument (good exit):

```
sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: `exit()` is primarily intended for interactive use. It is defined in `site.py` and therefore can be removed depending on how the site customization is performed. Note that it is conspicuously [absent from the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html).

Comment: Thanks you for the information, I how found I was useing, but with this information is better sys.exit. But I think is better in sys.exit pass 0 argument: sys.exit(0) for more clean and better learning.